# Map String -> &str from program args

Tags: rust, iterator, command-line-arguments

I am trying to map the program arguments which are given as Vec of String into a Vec of &str. I am using the `std::env::args()` iterator here:

```rust
let argv_as_refs: Vec<&str> = env::args().map(String::as_str).collect();
```

I think there is a question of lifetimes. I only need the `argv_as_refs` to pass into another function (the other function in question is part of a CXX-library, hence needing char** and not String objects).

I tried the code and got this error:

```bash
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
  --> src/main.rs:28:51
   |
28 |     let argv_as_refs: Vec<&str> = env::args().map(String::as_str).collect();
   |                                               --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                               |   |
   |                                               |   expected due to this
   |                                               |   found signature defined here
   |                                               required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = note: expected function signature `fn(String) -> _`
              found function signature `for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> _`
note: required by a bound in `map`

error[E0599]: the method `collect` exists for struct `Map<Args, for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r str {String::as_str}>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:28:67
   |
28 |     let argv_as_refs: Vec<&str> = env::args().map(String::as_str).collect();
   |                                                                   ^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Map<Args, for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r str {String::as_str}>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r str {String::as_str} as FnOnce<(String,)>>::Output = _`
           which is required by `Map<Args, for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r str {String::as_str}>: Iterator`
           `for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r str {String::as_str}: FnMut<(String,)>`
           which is required by `Map<Args, for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r str {String::as_str}>: Iterator`
           `Map<Args, for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r str {String::as_str}>: Iterator`
           which is required by `&mut Map<Args, for<'r> fn(&'r String) -> &'r str {String::as_str}>: Iterator`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- The result from `args()` is an iterator over owned `String`. As you `.map()` the iterator, there is noone to hold on to the memory backing each string; by the time the iterator is exhausted, the strings are gone, so the `&str` would be in an invalid state; someone needs to hold on to the that memory.
- Beware that `String` is UTF-8 encoded and may contain nul-bytes, which your FFI may not expect. Not all `String` are valid c-like strings. You'll need to make an extra trip through `CString` to check and/or add the required nul-byte at the end of the string.

```rust
use std::env;
use std::ffi;

// it's pointers all the way down
fn bar(args: *const *const ffi::c_char) {}


fn main() {
    // Convert the strings to c-style strings, causing a panic
    // if those strings contain nul-bytes (as they could, being utf-8)
    let args = env::args()
        .map(ffi::CString::new)
        .collect::<Result<Vec<ffi::CString>, _>>()
        .unwrap();

    // Create a new Vec to hold the pointers to the strings
    let args_as_c_char = args.iter().map(|s| s.as_ptr()).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    // Call our function
    bar(args_as_c_char.as_ptr());
}
```

Comment: I would append a null pointer to `args_as_c_char` (as with `argv`, or `environ`) because the signature of `bar()` does not expect the number of strings.

Comment: Your point is correct, I left out the size argument.

Answer (score 0):

The `Item` type of the iterator returned by `env::args()` is `String`. That means, in the `map` function, the value has been moved. If you rewrite that to use a closure, it might be easier to see what is happening:

```
env::args()
    .map(|s| {
        // s is moved into this closure
        s.as_str()
        // s will be dropped here
    })
    .collect();
```

The value being iterated over will get dropped inside the mapping function, so the mapping function cannot return a reference to it.

You can collect instead into a collection of `String`:

```
let args_owned: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
```

Then, if you actually needed a `Vec<&str>`, you can make references into that:

```
let argv_as_refs: Vec<&str> = args_owned.iter().map(String::as_str).collect();
```

This now works as you wanted because the strings are owned by the enclosing function and can be borrowed for that duration.